# skipdeployingnoopfunctions in firebase causing HTTP Error: 400, Cloud Run service 'function' does not exist in region `europe-west3` in this project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am having a issue in firebase where i can't deploy. When i run firebase deploy and have done changes to all codespaces every thing runs fine. But if there is no changes to my default codespace for functions i get the following error

```
HTTP Error: 400, Cloud Run service `function-name` does not exist in region `europe-west3` in this project
```

function-name in this case is a function that exists i the default codespace and it has a rewrite rule in firebase hosting.
since skipdeployingnoopfunctions has experimental support i guess that is a bug that will be solved.

Are there any workaround except run two separate deploy commands?
can i turn off skipdeployingnoopfunctions somehow?

I have tried to search if i can disable skipdeployingnoopfunctions without any luck

Comment: Having the same problem. Deploy works pretty bad, sometimes few functions are not deployed, and while trying to redeploy it's written that there were no changes to functions so nothing was deployed. How to turn off this setting? I have 50 functions and naming them all in the command is absurd

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could try deploying a single function.

E.g.

```
firebase deploy --only functions:app
```